# How to pass variable from actionCreate to _form.php?

Tags: yii, yii2

I have a create action of controller where I passed $ingredients array into the view

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    return $this->render('create', 
        ['model' => $model, 'ingredients' => Ingredient::find()->all()]
    );
}
```

In create.php I can acess $ingredients variable.
But if I try to access $ingredients in the _form.php

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'ingredient_id')->checkbox(
    ArrayHelper::map($ingredients, 'id', 'name')
) ?>
```

I get error

```
Undefined variable: ingredients
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by two ways
//first render the view file like this

```
    $params = [];
    $params['eqpType'] = $eqpType;
    $params['discountModel'] = $discountModel;
    $params['tabActive'] = $tabActive;
    $params['discountLabel'] = $discountLabel;

    echo $this->render('_form', $params);
```

//or you can include the code file directly ..in this case do not need to pass all perameters

```
    <?php include_once "_form.php";?>
```

Comment: The first approach helped

Comment: And how I can get in controller an array of checkboxes if name of checkbox is `Dish[ingredients][]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your are passing the variables to the `create` view, and your widget is in another view called `_form`. Go to the `create` view and make sure that all variables are passed to the `_form` view.

Answer (score 1):

in **create.php**

```
 <?php echo $this->render('_form', [
      'model' => $model,
      'ingredients' => $ingredients
 ]) ?>
```